# Lotus Notes: Displaying an image which is attached to a Rich Text Field in a document

Tags: richtextbox, document, lotus-notes, rtf

How do I do that? I have a rich text field where an Image is attached to but now I want to display that image directly in the document instead of double clicking the attachment to view the image.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this an existing document, or is this a document that you are creating in your code?

Comment: Is this for display in the client or on the web

Answer (score 0):

there are a few tricks to make this work, but my experience is that it often fails and display a red x to users instead of the image.

I suggest you do a composite application with a view and an xpage side by side, when user select the document or open it you display the image using the image control in the xpage.

[here is a link that descibe how you find the correct url to the image](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_URL_COMMANDS_FOR_OPENING_IMAGE_FILES_ATTACHMENTS_AND_OLE_OBJECTS.html)